# Can't find mechanize gem error require

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mechanize, require

So i've been using the mechanize gem fine on my OSX machine but now when i'm trying to use it on my Win10 machine i've run into some issues. Basically it can't find the mechanize gem for some reason. `C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require': cannot load such file -- mechanize (LoadError)`

Comment: There's an open issue logged regarding `nokogiri` support for Ruby 2.2 on Windows: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1256.  YMMV, but there are a few workarounds suggested in that thread.  Or you could use ruby 2.1.x.

Comment: Now it's not complaining about Nokogiri but still can't load mechanize.

    `C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mechanize (LoadError)`

Comment: It's not the old `require 'rubygems'` issue, is it? I'm not sure if that's still a thing in ruby 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use other gems on your win10 machine without error?

It looks like the error is with nokogiri not with mechanize. Which version of Nokogiri do you have installed?

I would try updating your gems with `gem update --system`

Comment: Updating didn't work and isn't Nokogiri installed with Mechanize? 
My editor (Rubymine) can't find Mechanize when trying to require.

Comment: in the error message it should say where it is looking for the gem. If you open windows explorer and navigate to that location, are you able to find the gem?

Comment: `C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require: cannot load such file -- mechanize (LoadError)`    

Mechanize is located in `C:\Ruby21-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\gems`

Comment: @slimeystuff were you ever able to get this working? I'm curious.If so, what was the solution?

Comment: I did. If I remember correctly I just made sure that the was absolutely no trace left of Ruby or any gem after uninstalling it. For some reason, it worked. Was a pain to delete everything though since small files were spread all over.

Comment: Did you switch ruby versions as well or this is working in 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it:

`gem install nokogiri`

Comment: There is no problem with nokogiri, it just can't find the mechanize gem.

Comment: `cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)` - so where this comes from? Did you try to install it?

Comment: According to the user orde it's a bug with version 2.2 of ruby, when I switched to 2.1 it stopped complaining about nokogiri, now I only get: 
`cannot load such file -- mechanize (LoadError)`

Answer (score 0):

you should run the desktop app "start command prompt with ruby" or do win+r (for run on windows) and type:

C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /E:ON /K C:\Ruby22-x64\bin\setrbvars.bat

once you are in there, run your command: gem install nokogiri

Answer (score -2):

apt-get install **ruby2.2-dev** should work :-)

Comment: On a Windows machine?